# WPF complex binding for custom control with sub-class as settings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, custom-controls

Right now I am trying to implement a custom control (which is of course way more complex than the demo solution I attached), and I kind of failed at passing a value down via binding.

First of all, the structure of the control:

- Control (this is basically a wrapper which passes down properties and handles common functionalities)
- Settings (this is a dependency property of the control and is a custom class as well)
  Text (this is a dependency property of the settings class)
- _renderer (this is a private field of the control which is responsible for rendering the control => in my real control it's just rendering a part of it, but for this example it's enough to just do it like that).

The goal of this is to pass the text from a control like a textbox or something down to the renderer which gets initialized with a reference to the settings.

The XAML which uses the control is written as follows:

```
<TextBox Text="Initial Text"
        x:Name="TextSource"
        Grid.Row="0" />
<local:CustomControl Grid.Row="1">
    <local:CustomControl.Settings>
        <local:CustomControlSettings Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=TextSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </local:CustomControl.Settings>
</local:CustomControl>
```

When I use the same XAML, but give the settings a fixed value for the "Text" then everything works as expected, but as soon as I change it to a binding, I don't even get the initial value any more.

Code with is passing down the text:

1. Passing the settings to the renderer

   ```
   private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       _renderer = new ControlRenderer();
       _renderer.Initialize(_renderArea, Settings);
   }
   ```
2. binding the settings text to the renderers internal text dependency property

   ```
   SetBinding(TextProperty, new Binding{Path = new PropertyPath(CustomControlSettings.TextProperty), Source = settings});
   ```

Note: you can uncomment this without any effect, so this should not be the problem if you ask me.

[And here´s a link to the demo solution I created](https://www.amazon.de/clouddrive/share/zmte1fiYI6lpc2Touc7WtLvalTCeAipOlUjWkYRFTp9?ref_=cd_ph_share_link_copy).

Comment: I wonder what your problem is. You change a binding and find troublesome that the previous value is lost?

Comment: the problem is, that the value from the textbox is never passed down ;)

Comment: somebody care to explain the -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After four hours of pain, later I found the solution. The problem is that the settings-object is not a part of the visual tree and therefore the dependency properties are not resolved.

So to be able to do things like this you need to add the settings to the visual tree. I did that by adding it to the canvas children inside of the CustomControl.

Comment: WPF binding tends to be extremely complicated.